# Maven gpg plugin cant find artifact

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-gpg-plugin

ive been trying to push my project into the maven repository and im trying to configure my maven gpg plugin correctly, im currently using it as

```
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

but it doesnt seem to be able to find my artifact since it gives the rr

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (default-cli) on project fitnesse-bootstrap-plus-theme: The project artifact has not been assembled yet. Please do not invoke this goal before the lifecycle phase "package".
```

my jar gets generated in the root/target folder.

Comment: How are you calling Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `maven-gpg-plugin` to phase `verify` which is executed after `package` phase and before `install` and `deploy` when you need signature to be installed / deployed.

So your configuration looks like:

```xml
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

You can also ommit `<phase>verify</phase>` because `maven-gpg-plugin` is default bind to correct phase.